# Java replaceAll with regex only replacing first instance

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I am trying to update all url's in a CSS string and my regex only seems to get the first one. I want to get anything like:

```
url("file")
url('file');
url(file);
```

I also want to exclude things where the url is data:

```
url("data: ...");
url('data: ...');
url(data: ...);
```

I wrote some code to do this, but it only replaces the first one:

```
String str = ".ff0{font-family:sans-serif;visibility:hidden;}@font-face{font-family:ff1;src:url(f1.woff)format(\"woff\");}.ff1{font-family:ff1;line-height:1.330566;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;visibility:visible;}@font-face{font-family:ff2;src:url(f2.woff)format(\"woff\");}.ff2{font-family:ff2;line-height:1.313477;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;visibility:visible;}@font-face{font-family:ff3;src:url(f3.woff)format(\"woff\");}.ff3{font-family:ff3;line-height:1.386719;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;visibility:visible;}@font-face{font-family:ff4;src:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI1IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUiPgo8cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iNSIgaGVpZ2h0PSI1IiBmaWxsPSIjOWU5ZTllIj48L3JlY3Q+CjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wIDVMNSAwWk02IDRMNCA2Wk0tMSAxTDEgLTFaIiBzdHJva2U9IiM4ODgiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iMSI+PC9wYXRoPgo8L3N2Zz4=)format(\"woff\");";
str = str.replaceAll("url\\((['\"]?)(?!data)(.*)\\1\\)","url(someURL/$2)");
out.println(str);
```

Any ideas on how to fix? I imagine it has something to do with the regex.

Comment: str = str.replaceAll(/url\\((['\"]?)(?!data)(.*)\\1\\)/g,"url(someURL/$2)"); You need to set the global identifier... the /g

Comment: Aren't you thinking of javascript? When I do this in java, I get a load of errors.

Comment: Whoops... been in JS land all day, misread the title...

Comment: Try with reluctant quantifier. So instead of `(.*)` use `(.*?)`

Comment: `str = str.replaceAll("url\\((['\"]?)(?!data)(.*?)\\1\\)", "url($1someURL/$2$1)");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use non-greedy quantifier (`*?` instead of `*`).

To exclude the `data` entries properly, also use possessive quantifier for capturing the qoutes: `?+` instead of `?`.

So your regex should look as follows:
`url\((['"]?+)(?!data)(.*?)\1\)`
Note that you should probably escape some characters with extra slash as you did in your example.

Comment: That works thanks. Just one issue that I need to solve is that when data is surrounded by single or double quotes, it passes the regex. How would I fix that?

Comment: For that you would want to use possessive quantifier for matching these quotes: `?+` instead of `?`: `url\((['"]?+)(?!data)(.*?)\1\)`

Answer (score 2):

Your `.*` is greedy. It's capturing to the end of the string.  Use `.*?`, instead, which will force the engine to capture as few characters as possible.

```
str = str.replaceAll("url\\((['\"]?)(?!data)(.*?)\\1\\)","url(someURL/$2)");
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to fix the issue where it would apply when data is surrounded by single or double quotes?

Comment: I'm not clear what exact issue you're trying to address.  The regex above already captures a url that is within single or double quotes into the second capture group.  Are you trying to retain quotes after the string replacement?

Comment: If you look above at the data urls I posted to exclude, this regex only excludes ones without single and double quotes. I want to make sure that it excludes all data urls.

Comment: Sorry.  I missed that you wanted to exclude _data_ above.  Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
~\((?!.*data).+\)~
```